# Can an automaton be produced for a language that outputs undefined for the empty string?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

Say I have the below language and I would like to produce an automaton for it:

$$
{ \{ s \mid  \text{length}(s) \div \text{length(filter}(s)) = 2\}}
$$

- length returns the length of the string
- filter returns its input string without any letter a's

It is to be noted that upon inputting the empty string in such a language, the output is undefined.

Can an automaton be produced despite having the empty string as input return an undefined output?

Comment: (1) What is the alphabet? (2) An automaton does not output anything. (3) Maybe the language you want is the set of all words $u$ such that $|u| = 2|u|_b$ (if the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$). If this is the case, it is not a regular language.

Comment: It is simple to avoid division by zero by defining the automaton as $\{ s \mid  \text{length}(s) = 2\,\text{length(filter}(s))\}$, in which case you should accept the empty string.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin (1) The alphabet is {a, b} - I didn't specify it as I thought it was not required (3) Yes, that is what I want. Why is that not a regular language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$, one has $|u| = |u|_a + |u|_b$, where, as usual,
$|u|_a$ denotes the number of occurrences of $a$ in $u$ and $|u|$ is the length of $u$. Now, $|u| = 2|u|_b$ if and only if $|u|_a + |u|_b = 2|u|_b$, that is, $|u|_a = |u|_b$.

Suppose that the language $L = \{ u \in \{a,b\}^* \mid |u|_a = |u|_b \}$ is regular. Then the language $L \cap a^*b^*$ would also be regular. But $L \cap a^*b^* = \{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$, the standard example of a context-free, but non-regular language. The proof can be found in any textbook on automata, and can be proved using Nerode's equivalence or by the pumping lemma.

Comment: What if instead of an alphabet of {a, b}, you would have {a, b, c, d} and filter() would filter both a and b? Would the proof still work? Thanks for your answer, explained rly well. Edit: Sorry if it is not a brilliant question, I'm new to formal languages and automata

Comment: It would not change much. The language $L$ would now be $\{ u \in \{a,b\}^* \mid |u|_a = |u|_b + |u|_c + |u|_d \}$ , but the intersection of $L$ with $a^*b^*$ would still be $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ !

Comment: Interesting. I thought the language $L$ would now be $\{u∈{a,b}∗∣|u|_a+|u|_b=|u|_c+|u|_d\}$ given that filtering both filters a and b, that's why I asked. Cool, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I read your comment too fast and just changed the alphabet. If you change the filter as well, your formula is correct. Now, you could consider the intersection with $a^*c^*$ to get $\{a^nc^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$.

Comment: The intersection would not be $\{(ab)^n(cd)^n\ | \ n\ge 0\}$?

Comment: No, there is no $b$ and no $d$ in $a^*c^*$...

Answer (score 1):

The language $L:={ \{ s \mid  \text{length}(s) \div \text{length(filter}(s)) = 2\}}$ is not regular.

You can see it using the *pumping lemma* :

Assume (for contradiction) that $L$ is regular. Then there is some integer $l$ such that whenever a word $w\in L$ has length greater than $l$, there are words $u_1,v,u_2$ satisfying :

- $v\neq \epsilon$
- $length(u_1v)\leqslant l$
- $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, u_1v^nu_2\in L$

Now consider the word
$$w:=\underbrace{aa\dots a}_{l \textrm{ times}}\underbrace{bb\dots b}_{l \textrm{ times}}$$

$w\in L$ and $length(w)\geqslant l$, hence we can find $u_1,v,u_2$ as above, hence $w':=u_1v^2u_2\in L$, but $w'$ has strictly more than $l$ "$a$"s, while it has $l$ "b"s (and no other letters), hence $w' \notin L$, a contradiction.

Comment: The moral of the story is that a finite automaton can only have a finite memory. :)